# Veewee, Vagrant, Puppet, Erlang and RabbitMQ

Tags: puppet

I am kinda stuck with a problem I am trying to wrap my head around for days now.

Here is what I am doing:

1. By using Veewee, I am creating a VirtualBox image and then I create a Vagrant box from it. See [here](http://bit.ly/RfPnBR), [here](http://bit.ly/LAxzjy)
2. Finally I run puppet from Vagrant to install RabbitMQ, see [here](http://bit.ly/Mb0D0v).

Veewee, Vagrant and VirtualBox all run on MacOS X 10.7.4. The vagrant box itself is CentOS 6.2.

This worked fine for quite some time until I was recreating the VirtualBox image a couple of days ago. During installation of the rabbitmq-plugins during my puppet run I now get the following error:

```
/Stage[main]/Rabbitmq/Exec[rabbitmq-plugins]/returns: erlexec: HOME must be set
```

My RabbitMQ puppet configuration can be found [on my GitHub repo](https://github.com/tobias-wissmueller/dev_ops_central/blob/master/modules/rabbitmq/manifests/init.pp) for that project, but here is the most important part:

```
$version = "2.8.7"
$url     = "http://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-server/v${version}/rabbitmq-server-${version}-1.noarch.rpm"

package{"erlang":
    ensure => "present",
}

package{"rabbitmq-server":
    provider => "rpm",
    source   => $url,
    require  => Package["erlang"]
}

exec{"rabbitmq-plugins":
    path    => "/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin",
    command => "rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management",
    require => Package["rabbitmq-server"]
}
```

My additional repositories, e.g. epel, are defined in veewees [postinstall.sh](https://github.com/tobias-wissmueller/dev_ops_central/blob/master/definitions/dev_ops_central/postinstall.sh) right at the top of the file.

Finally, this is what I get when I do '/etc/init.d/rabbitmq-server status'

```
[{pid,2834},
{running_applications,[{rabbit,"RabbitMQ","2.8.7"},
                    {ssl,"Erlang/OTP SSL application","4.1.6"},
                    {public_key,"Public key infrastructure","0.13"},
                    {crypto,"CRYPTO version 2","2.0.4"},
                    {mnesia,"MNESIA  CXC 138 12","4.5"},
                    {os_mon,"CPO  CXC 138 46","2.2.7"},
                    {sasl,"SASL  CXC 138 11","2.1.10"},
                    {stdlib,"ERTS  CXC 138 10","1.17.5"},
                    {kernel,"ERTS  CXC 138 10","2.14.5"}]},
{os,{unix,linux}},
{erlang_version,"Erlang R14B04 (erts-5.8.5) [source] [64-bit] [rq:1] [async-threads:30] [kernel-poll:true]\n"},
{memory,[{total,24993120},
      {processes,10328496},
      {processes_used,10321296},
      {system,14664624},
      {atom,1175905},
      {atom_used,1143841},
      {binary,17192},
      {code,11416020},
      {ets,766168}]},
{vm_memory_high_watermark,0.4},
{vm_memory_limit,205851852},
{disk_free_limit,1000000000},
{disk_free,7089795072},
{file_descriptors,[{total_limit,924},
                {total_used,4},
                {sockets_limit,829},
                {sockets_used,2}]},
{processes,[{limit,1048576},{used,131}]},
{run_queue,0},
{uptime,6}]
```

Sources in the web suggest, that I have to set HOME. Of course I was logging into the box if HOME was set, for user vagrant it was '/home/vagrant' and for root it was 'root'.

As always, any hints/ideas/suggestions/assumptions are more than welcome.

Thanks a lot!

Cheers,
Tobi

Comment: Are you actually solving a problem?

Comment: Sure, my goal is to create two vagrant boxes, one with a sensu client and one with a sensu server. Since I am new to puppet, am experimenting a lot, that requires me to have vagrant to be able to destroy a box and build it up again. It already worked fine. Having only the ISO image and a few files on GitHub, I was able to do so, but not any more.

Comment: And what is the problem exactly? You have a puppet file to install rabbitmq, and it seems to run just fine ?

Comment: Actually, not quite ... It runs fine until '/Stage[main]/Rabbitmq/Exec[rabbitmq-plugins]/returns: erlexec: HOME must be set', see my post, and then I get '/Stage[main]/Rabbitmq/Service[rabbitmq-server]: Dependency Exec[rabbitmq-plugins] has failures: true'. All other resources that would be applied afterwards fail because of this failed dependency.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I ran into this same issue after upgrading to Puppet 3.0.

From the [release notes](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/3/reference/release_notes.html#changes-to-core-resource-types) I eventually found this:

> Due to misleading values, the HOME and USER environment variables are now unset when running commands.

The solution that worked for me was adding `environment => "HOME=/root"` to the Exec resource:

```
exec{"rabbitmq-plugins":
    path        => "/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin",
    environment => "HOME=/root",
    command     => "rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management",
    require     => Package["rabbitmq-server"]
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot, this helped. My mistake was, that I have set the environment variable in a separate exec-resource, assuming this will apply for all other exec-resources as well. Obviously it doesn't.